# Подняться на несколько уровней, используя XPath

Tags: xpath, selenium

Дорый день.

У меня есть грид на странице, данные которого можно изменять. При нажатии на ячейку может появиться `TextArea`, `ComboBox` или календарь, в зависимости от ячейки.

Проблема в том, что выпадающий контрол появляется не в гриде, а несколько парентов выше.

Данная реализация будет использоваться в `selenium`, и потому при нажатии определенной ячейки нужно идти вверх от нее, чтобы найти нужный элемент.

Я делаю так:

```
var parent = element.FindElements(By.XPath("..//..//..//..//..//..//..//..//..//..//*"));
```

и дальше уже ищу нужний контрол в parent.

Вопрос:

1) как можно лучше написать XPath, чтобы подняться на несколько уровней выше без `..//..//..//`, потому что в некоторых местах нужно подниматься на 16 парентов?

2) можно ли как-то через XPath, в моем случае искать конкретный контрол?

Например

```
if(element.FindElements(By.XPath("..//..//..//..//..//..//..//..//..//..//textArea[class = 'blabla']")).Count > 0)
```

Как лучше реализовать такую задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то:

```
ancestor::textArea[class = 'blabla']
```

Хотя как textArea может быть чьим-то предком, не совсем понятно. Может быть, так:

```
ancestor::*/textArea[class = 'blabla']
```

ЗЫ Для Firefox'а есть плагин [Selenium-IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp), там можно найти xpath для элемента, просто кликнув на него.

Comment: Не совсем точно. Выходит, что селениум кликает по ячейке в гриде и появляется textArea, но не в гриде, а выше по разметке. Так, как сейчас селениум видит конкретную ячейку, а не всю разметку страницы, которая изменилась после клика, нужно от элемента выйти выше по парентам, чтобы увидить всю разметку и найти нужную textArea.
Предложенный Вами способ, к сожалению, не работает. ((

Comment: @Telsystems, разметку приведите. По вашему описанию должен работать второй вариант. Лучше слов расскажет код.

Answer (score 1):

Самый элегантный из способов, думаю, искать парент,в котором и будут появлятся все дочерние елементы. А потом искать дочерние элементы внутри этого парента, а не внутри документа.

Через ".//ваш xpath" (именно что то конкретное что ты пишешь после "..//..//..//..//..//..//..//..//..//..//")